# Loading an image in Java without AWT

Tags: java, awt, embedded-linux

I am on an embedded platform without access to AWT. I was wondering if anyone knew of a standalone library to load images without any AWT involvement.

Thanks,
Braden McDorman

Comment: AWT can work in headless mode, without a display. Are you without access to awt library, or without access to an X environment?

Comment: Without an X environment. We wanted to load them to a frame-buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps AWT headless mode can help?

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/

Answer (score 1):

I took the semi-easy way out and created a tool to convert images to RGB565 raw files. Then I have a custom loader.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at JIMI.

http://java.sun.com/products/jimi/

Easy to work with, bought by Sun, superceeded by JAI which is not as easy to work with.

(And now the page is Oracle-branded...)

Answer (score 0):

Not a standalone library and not sure what your platform *offers*, but you can try the [javax.imageio.ImageIO](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) (Java SE 1.4 and later).
Just use one of the `read` methods to get a `BufferedImage`.